# How to use SwiperJS (npm package) in VueJS (CDN)

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, swiper.js

I have basic problem, but i don't know, how to solve it.

I am using Twig templates, where **SwiperJS is installed via npm**. I import all Swiper dependencies which I needed, to app.js. Where is no Vue, swiper works absolutely fine.

BUT on one Twig template I am using **VueJS via CDN** for entire page. Vue is working fine, all Swiper styles working fine too, but scripts for swiping not.

I know the problem - this swiper is **#app** (it has to be there) and thats the reason, why is it not working.

Can some help me, how to solve this?

FYI I cant use **import**.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion on this page you can try to use vue-awesome-swiper whcih will not create problems.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-awesome-swiper